# How can I make Cocoa bindings update during menu tracking?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm using Cocoa bindings to control the enabling and disabling of buttons and menu items in my app, and in general it is working very nicely.  However, there is one issue: the enabling does not update during menu tracking.

My app runs a long task, started by the user.  That task runs in the background, and so control is returned to the run loop as soon as the task starts.  The user can do other things while the task is going; however, there are some things that the user cannot do while a task is running, and some things that the user can do only when a task is running.  I want menu items and buttons related to such things to disable/enable while the task is running, and enable/disable, reciprocally, when the task finishes.

In general this works great; I've got it all working.  The only problem is that if the user is tracking through the menu bar at the point in time when the task finishes, the menu items do not change their enabling until the user stops tracking.  This means that the user can actually select a menu item that ought to have been disabled, because the enable state of the menu item has not yet been updated.

So I just need a call that I can make at the moment my task finishes that triggers an immediate re-evaluation of enable states based on bindings.  Is there a way?

(Note this is not related to multithreading.  The task is actually performed on the main thread (for various reasons) using delayed perform requests.  So the task finishes during such a run loop perform on the main thread, sets the "finished" property immediately, and then returns, allowing menu tracking to continue.  The problem is that AppKit apparently does not do anything with enabling during the menu tracking.)

**UPDATE:**
As explained in the comments below, I am an idiot.  I had switched over to using validateMenuItem: for my menu item enabling, and then forgot that I had done so.  So the problem was real, but it was about validateMenuItem:, not about bindings.  Anyway, for anybody who finds this post and actually wants to know how to force the menubar to re-update, the quick answer is -[NSMenu update], the long answer that I arrived at is:

```
- (void)forceImmediateMenuUpdate
{
    // So, the situation is that the simulation has stopped playing because the end of the simulation was reached.  If that happens while the user
    // is tracking a menu in the menu bar, the menus do not get updating (enabling, titles) until the user ends menu tracking.  This is sort of a
    // bug in Cocoa, I guess; it assumes that state that influences menu bar items does not change while the user is tracking menus, which is false
    // in our case, but is true for most applications, I suppose, maybe.  Anyway, we need to force an immediate update in this situation.
    NSMenu *mainMenu = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainMenu];
    NSInteger numberOfSubmenus = [mainMenu numberOfItems];

    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < numberOfSubmenus; ++itemIndex)
    {
        NSMenuItem *menuItem = [mainMenu itemAtIndex:itemIndex];
        NSMenu *submenu = [menuItem submenu];

        [submenu update];
    }
}
```

I call that method at the point where my task finishes, and the menus all update themselves even as the user is tracking them.  (Which is obviously a questionable thing to do in general, but here it is just enabling/disabling items, not shuffling them around under the user's mouse :->)

I hope this helps somebody.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Is the `finished` property registered as a dependent keyPath for the properties those menu items are bound to?  Look into `keyPathsForValuesAffecting...`  If `finished` is a KVC compliant keyPath, and your bindings are dependent on it, you'll get the immediacy you want.

Comment: Are you *sure* the delayed-perform requests are firing during menu tracking? If you use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, that will only fire when the run loop is running in `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`. During menu tracking it is running in a different mode, `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`. You would need to use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:` and specify the modes to get it fire during menu tracking.

Comment: stevesliva, the menu items in question have their "enable" binding directly bound to the "finished" property, so keyPathsForValuesAffecting... does not seem relevant.  That binding works fine, except that the updating of the enable state does not occur while menu tracking is going on.  For example, I can (1) start the task, (2) start menu tracking, and (3) see via updates in my window that the task has finished, but the menu items do not change.  If I (4) let go of the mouse button (stopping tracking) and then (5) immediately click again, the menu items are now correctly enabled.

Comment: Ken Thomases, yes, I'm sure.  :->  I'm specifying NSRunLoopCommonModes with my performs.  My app's window updates continuously showing the progress of the task, and that updating continues throughout menu tracking.  I can see, during menu tracking, that the task has finished.  And in fact, buttons in my app's window that also use bindings for their enabling do change their enabling at the moment that the task finishes; so the bindings do fire immediately for them.  It is only the menu items that... oooooh.  Whoops.  I am an idiot, and I should close this question.  See next comment.

Comment: OK, so here's why I'm an idiot.  :->  I did have the app designed exactly as described above... until I changed it.  The menu items now get enabled/disabled using validateMenuItem:.  And then I totally spaced out that I had made that change.  Sigh.  Sorry for the noise.  Of course, now I have a new question: how can I get validateMenuItem: to happen while menu tracking is ongoing?  :->  But I think I will be able to figure that out, probably.

Comment: Should I now delete this post?  I don't know the conventions on stackoverflow for this sort of thing...